# How to host gatsby with wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, web-hosting, gatsby

I'm building a headless WordPress site with Gatsby. On WordPress, I create a post, using REST API. Get that post to Gatsby and display it.  The question is how to host it on the live domain?

So using FileZilla, I put in public_html WordPress files and gatsby build version in there. The result: On startup file, the gatsby website is working. However, if I try to visit the nonexistent page I get redirected to the WordPress theme. Also on gatsby build version favicon icons are working, but on live version is not found, because I get redirected to a WordPress not found page.

[Live Website](https://www.itarnas.lt/)

[Using Underscore Theme](https://underscores.me/)

[Github Gatsby](https://github.com/ArnasDickus/itarnas-portfolio)

So the expected results would be. I don't want to see WordPress themes, and favicon icons should work as they worked on the Gatsby built version.

Directory Structure
[image]

Comment: What does your folder structure look like?

Comment: Added folder structure image. It's in the public_html folder. I don't think domain files are relevant, because I didn't change them. So I didn't include them. I think the possible fix could be to create a redirect for a theme,  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17969/disable-front-end-to-use-as-cms-only

Comment: Did you try the possible fix yet?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. Sadly not really useful. Now with added redirect entering any non-existent link. will put me back to the main site. However, I also can't access favicon icons. As well as Gatsby's own 404 page. I'm going to look into hosting in netlify with a custom domain name

Answer (score 1):

The better way is to use a static site hosting like [Netlify](https://netlify.com).

You will thus have your front which will be totally separated from the CMS, and in addition, it is free.

Comment: So I'm trying to launch it on netlify. Now waiting for DNS configuration to take effect. In order to launch on live domain.

Comment: So how do you connect on netlify deployed website to WordPress? I deployed the website to netlify successfully, https://itarnas.lt/ however, I no longer have access WordPress files on my domain. So how do you put them both together on one domain? Or where else would you host WordPress?

Comment: You can add a subdomaine to your domain (like admin.itarnas.lt) and point it to your host that contain your WP install :)

Comment: One developer tried that, however, he couldn't make it work with netlify first post. https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/16330 It might be worth investigating if it's really true, or ditch netlify all together, and use subdomains.